# PyCharm: how to use debug mode

Tags: python, pycharm

I've never used an IDE so probably my problem is really basic.
When I start the debug mode, it shows me only this empty screen
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xitPp.png)

How can I let it start correctly?

Comment: Start by adding some breakpoints ;)

Comment: Oh... :D but what if I want to stop the program for example after a number of while cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add breakpoints by clicking on the sidebar near the line count.

Then, when you will start a debugging session the execution of the code will stop at your breakpoint, you can then uses the multiple controls to navigate in your code.

You will also see the variables related to your code.